# check if a variable is null or not, on sequence flows in camunda modeler

Tags: javascript, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler, juel

On a sequenceFlow, I want to check a condition which may include a variable that may not be defined yet in process instance.
so if it's not defined, I dont want to get ActivitiException of "the variable is not defined", but want the flow to proceed.

I wrote my condition like this:

${ A == null || A.a >= B.b }

then when A is null (not defined yet) I cant proceed :/

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a workaround, but you could use an ExecutionListener and init the value when your process starts, so you’ll never have a Null value